# Can I export Postgres query results from DataGrip to parquet format?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, data-science, parquet, datagrip

I have a large Postgres query I'd like to export to parquet format using DataGrip.

I've installed a few IntelliJ plugins that support the parquet format, such as Big Data File Viewer, Big Data Tools, and Remote File Systems:

[image]

But neither the query results window...

[image]

Nor the Export Data window...

[image]

Show an option to export data in parquet format. Does anyone know if this can be done, and if so, how to do it?

**Note**: This is a production system so I can't install anything on the database server or host. Any answers involving making changes to the server-side environment are unfortunately not possible. However, I have full control over the client-side environment and can install whatever tools are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Export to parquet format is still a feature request for now on DataGrip - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16632 - You may vote for it using the thumbs-up